# Netbeans no longer downloads output files from remote build host

Tags: c++, netbeans, remote-access

Netbeans 8.2 under Windows is used to develop applications for the Raspberry Pi, including Qt based, wherein the Raspberry Pi serves as the remote build host.

According to the [tutorial](https://netbeans.org/kb/docs/cnd/remotedev-tutorial.html#tips)

> If building your project remotely compiles libraries or generates
> other files in addition to the main build product, the IDE prompts you
> to download the files to the local system. You can select which
> changed files to download.

The problem that this no longer happens: it neither downloads anything nor prompts me. I can't figure out why. Please help me to restore this functionality.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turned out to be a bug in Netbeans, that prevented the downloading of changed files if the path contained a space. It was fixed in a recent patch.